# Finding value of another attribute given an attribute

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a CSV that has multiple lines, and I am looking to find the `JobTitle` of a person, given their name. The CSV is now in a DataFrame `sal` as such:

```
id    employee_name    job_title
1     SOME NAME        SOME TITLE
```

I'm trying to find the `JobTitle` of some given persons name, but am having a hard time doing this. I am currently trying to learn pandas by doing crash courses and I know I can get a list of job titles by using `sal['job_title']`, but that gives me an entire list of the job titles.

**How can I find the value of a specific person?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
sal[sal.employee_name == 'name']
```

If need select only some column, use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) with `boolean indexing`:

```
sal.ix[sal.employee_name == 'name', 'job_title']
```

Sample:

```
sal = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],
                   'employee_name':['name','name1','name2'],
                   'job_title':['titleA','titleB','titleC']},
                    columns=['id','employee_name','job_title'])

print (sal)
   id employee_name job_title
0   1          name    titleA
1   2         name1    titleB
2   3         name2    titleC

print (sal[sal.employee_name == 'name'])
   id employee_name job_title
0   1          name    titleA

print (sal.ix[sal.employee_name == 'name', 'job_title'])
0    titleA
Name: job_title, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Huge help. Will accept when SO allows